# Upgrade from 16.04 to 16.10 and lost my /dev/ttyUSBX devices

Tags: serial-port

I upgraded from Xenial Xerus to Yakkety Yak and I lost all ability to connect to my /dev/ttyUSB0-2. Now dmesg | grep tty returns the following:

`:~/Desktop$ dmesg | grep tty
[    0.000000] console [tty0] enabled
[    1.222490] 00:06: ttyS0 at I/O 0x3f8 (irq = 4, base_baud = 115200) is a 16550A
[    5.862329] usb 4-3: cp210x converter now attached to ttyUSB0
[    8.030587] usb 4-3: usbfs: interface 0 claimed by cp210x while 'brltty' sets config #1
[    8.032694] cp210x ttyUSB0: cp210x converter now disconnected from ttyUSB0
[  804.989176] usb 5-5: usbfs: USBDEVFS_CONTROL failed cmd brltty rqt 128 rq 6 len 255 ret -62`

What the heck happened?

My scanner police scanner connected to /dev/ttyS0 works fine and so do my jump drives when plugged into my USB ports. Looks like it's an issue with devices that have embedded USB to serial converters. Linux never required drivers for those.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer in a bug report from 2011 and chose to uninstall brltty:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/brltty/+bug/874181

I didn't have to do this with 15.10 or 16.04.